# Multiple workers with gevent-socketio fails with xhr-polling transport because of sessions

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent, gunicorn

I'm currently trying to scale [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) across multiple workers with the gunicorn server using the worker **socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker**. I'm using websockets when it exists otherwise I'm forcing XHR-polling (for IE etc).

XHR-polling needs a session to keep track of the following polls but as soon as I go from one to two or more workers the requests starts spreading out between themselves which means the state is lost and everything breaks down.

I think the following lines of code is relevant:
https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/socketio/handler.py#L104-106
I suppose I need some other storage engine, for example redis which I'm using for regular pubsub-actions but this is deep inside the actual library.

So my question is how do I go from in-memory session storage to another backend engine globally in my application (does it gracefully override the session code in the link above?) **without** having to modify the library itself? [Something like PHP's session directives in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler). I suppose an argument could be made that this is a very generic python question but I'm having trouble to find relevant information, and I'm also unsure that it'll work for this library.

Or in the alternative, how do I use gevent-socketio's xhr-polling transport across different workers and servers (without stickyness)?

Thanks!

Comment: Just an idea: keep session-specific info in cookies? A kind of REST.

Comment: @moodh Did you ever solve this? Also, do multiple workers really help anyway? Gevent itself does a great job at handling many calls in a single event loop already.

Comment: No, I gave up and started using http://pusher.com/ instead. There's some tickets in gevent-socketio (https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/112) regarding this problem but I don't know how far they've come. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously a limitation of socketio. From what I can see on the web, session handling is typically done at web framework layer rather than web server one. socketio tries to do it on its own, lower layer, and does it in a limited manner. I guess the authors thought a full-fledged solution would be an overkill. In your case, they proved to be wrong.

There are only two ways to overcome limitations that require logic change: patching the source and patching in the runtime. Choose whichever pleases you the most (or, well, disgusts the least :^) ). **For the 2nd option, I suggest to replace `request_tokens` and/or the code that creates it with another entity with the same interface.** Due to the reasons stated in the 1st paragraph, I really think that socketio authors are likely to accept a source patch that would allow it to utilize external session handling mechanisms if you propose one.

Standard locations for session information are: shared memory, files, database. I suggest you change the logic in such a way that socketio uses the same mechanism as your web framework (or whatever composes your pages) does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Although it's not a solution i'll still award the bounty for your information. I'll wait around for an actual solution but your reply helped me understand the problem even more. I'm pretty sure we'll end up solving it by replacing the request_tokens like you suggested. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: 2moodh: I suggested the fix to "use the same mechanism as your web framework does". So it's impossible to write without knowing what this mechanism is.

Comment: I use redis to keep sessions between workers and servers, nothing specific for flask (the framework I'm using). It might be possible to let Flask use Redis but I havn't looked into that yet. :)

Comment: I did my best to work out an actual solution but it proved too hard to find the ins and outs by just navigating the code without looking into an actual system at runtime. The `request_tokens` dict seems to be composed out of a cookie (so it should persist between requests) and I couldn't track the origins of other server entities the code uses. I really don't think that 20 points justify any further time investment.

Comment: ivan_pozdeev: Thanks for trying tho! https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/112 here's an active ticket with the current problem as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples here:

https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples/pyramid_backbone_redis_chat_persistence

It shows how to use redis as a distributed message queue

Comment: I already use redis inside the application itself, which works fine. You do not seem to understand my problem though. It's the actual long polling socket handling deep in the library itself that's the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, as I am having the same issue; instead of letting gunicorn fork (with the -w flag), maybe you could spawn multiple process of gunicorn on different ports, then use nginx to balance on them using an ["upstream" block with "sticky" session](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky). I believe that is how the nodejs implementation handles multiprocessing of workers when not sharing states with Redis.